# Problemas com XML Linq usando namespace .net

Tags: .net, xml, linq

Estou usando um namespace no momento que crio meu xml, porém o 'xmlns' também está aparecendo na tag abaixo da raiz, isso está me prejudicando, como posso fazer para o 'xmlns' ficar apernas na tag root(TLote_GNRE)? 
Segue o código:

```
Dim xDoc As New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing))
Dim nS As XNamespace = "http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br"

Dim xGuias As XElement = New XElement("guias")
xDoc.Add(New XElement(nS + "TLote_GNRE", xGuias))

Dim sw As New StringWriter()
Dim xWrite As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw)

xDoc.Save(xWrite)
xWrite.Close()

xDoc.Save("C:\xml.xml")
```

XML saída:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <TLote_GNRE xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br">
 <guias xmlns=""/>
</TLote_GNRE>
```

Answer (score 1):

Retirando a variável `nS` daqui:

```
xDoc.Add(New XElement(nS + "TLote_GNRE", xGuias))
```

Acho que ficou confuso o jeito que você usou. O correto seria usar assim:

```
Dim raiz As XElement = New XElement("TLote_GNRE", new XAttribute("Xmlns", ns))

Dim xGuias As XElement = New XElement(ns + "guias")
raiz.Add(xGuias)
xDoc.Add(raiz)
```

Note que `"guias"` também precisa do *namespace*.

Comment: então, mas a tag 'guias' é filha da tag 'TLote_GNRE', e a tag 'TLote_GNRE' precisa do namespace que citei.

Comment: Então, mas aí você só passa o *namespace* pro elemento raiz, e não pro elemento filho.

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na resposta que acho que não ficou claro o suficiente. Veja agora.

Comment: Entendi o que vc quis dizer agora, porém existe um erro no momento que passa o xNamespace.Xmlns. "Valor de tipo System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace' não pode ser convertido para 'System.Xml.Linq.XName'."

Comment: Experimente trocar `XNamespace.Xmlns` por `"xmlns"`. Qualquer coisa atualizo a resposta.

Comment: usei o xmlns como string, porém a saída de xml é identica a que comentei, a tag 'guias' ainda continua saindo com o xmlns

Comment: Você tem razão. Comi bola. "guias" também precisa do *namespace*. Veja agora.

Comment: Amigo, acho que estamos falando de coisas diferentes, o problema que estou tento é que na tag filha 'guias' está aparecendo o 'xmlns' e quero deixar isso apenas no root, pois assim sei que tudo que vem depois pertence aquele namespace e assim consigo validar no WebService, digo isso pq ja fiz alguns testes aqui do jeito que estou falando, porém fiz a xml na unha

Comment: Então, mas o elemento filho precisa ter o mesmo *namespace* do elemento pai (no seu caso, o raiz), senão o interpretador pensa que o elemento filho pertence a outro *namespace*. Você testou agora com essa minha última edição?

Comment: Entendi, do jeito que vc fez realmente entrou o namespace na tag filha, porém depois eu tenho que dar continuidade nessa xml, e não consigo mais encontrar a tag filha como <guias>, porém sem namespace eu encontro, faço o seguinte para encontrar: 'xDoc.Elements.<guias>(0)'

Comment: Bom, aí já acho que isso seria dúvida para outra pergunta.